# NodeJS/Express - Routing with Regex

Tags: regex, node.js, express, routes

I am trying to get a Regex Route working with Express.

I want it, to respond to all routes that are the following pattern: Three Numbers, X Amount of Letters - The Matching Regex for this is `[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]+`  - So it should match an url like: `xyz.com/001ab`

However, somehow my Routing does not seem to be working - I'm trying the following:

```
 app.get(/\/[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]+/, campaigns.redirectToLandingPage);
```

Somehow though, this does not work as expected and it wont pick up the url.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfectly for me, could you provide some example routes that are not working and the version of express you are using?